# HK2 dependency injection in multiple servlets

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jetty, hk2

We have a REST API server based on Jetty 9.3 and Jersey 2.7

Dependency injection works fine with HK2 that comes bundled with the libs. We register the needed services to the application `Handler` via a `ResourceConfig` and have something like:

`handler.addServlet(new ServletHolder("main-api", new ServletContainer(resourceConfig)), MAIN_SERVLET_PATH + "/*");`

We then wanted to move some of the HTTP end-points to a separate "admin" port. So we created two separate `ServerConnector`s, one for each port, and two separate `Handler`s wrapping separate `ServletHolder`s that are mapped to the relevant pathSpecs, for each relevant path ("/admin" and "/api").

The problem is that each of the Handlers now creates a separate `ServiceLocator` with its own set of managed services. We thereby cannot share services between admin and api end-points - Singleton objects defined in both handlers are created twice.

Tried creating a "bridge" between the two ServiceLocators - but that causes issues with scoped resources. Tried creating a third ServiceLocator and bridging it to the two other locators - not good either.

Any ideas how one can share DI objects between separate handlers in Jetty? Or have an alternative idea of how the above can be achieved?

Comment: Not sure if it will work, but you can try to set [this property as an init-param](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.26/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/ServletProperties.html#SERVICE_LOCATOR) passing your created locator as the init-param value.

Answer (score 0):

thanks [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet), your suggestion indeed solved the issue

```
ContextHandler defaultContext;
ContextHandler adminContext;
AbstractBinder sharedSingeltons;

ServiceLocator sharedServiceLocator = ServiceLocatorUtilities.bind("shared-locator", sharedSingeltons); 
defaultContext.setAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR, sharedServiceLocator);
adminContext.setAttribute(ServletProperties.SERVICE_LOCATOR, sharedServiceLocator);
```